# IIS Reverse proxy with multiple rules

Tags: iis, url-rewriting, reverse-proxy, arr

```
<rewrite>
        <rules>
            <rule name="ReverseProxyInboundRule1" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="^a/(.*)" />
                <action type="Rewrite" url="http://localhost:8086/{R:1}" />
            </rule>
            <rule name="ReverseProxyInboundRule2" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="^b/(.*)" />
                <action type="Rewrite" url="http://localhost:8085/{R:1}" logRewrittenUrl="true" />
            </rule>
        </rules>
    </rewrite>
```

At any point of time only one of the rule works another gives 404 error. 
if http://localhost/a/xxx works then http://localhost/b/yyy gives 404 error.

Comment: Mistake 3 https://blog.lextudio.com/the-very-common-mistakes-when-using-iis-url-rewrite-module-a2ab7e4fee59

Answer (score 0):

Both rules work side by side in my environment.Did you get 404.4 error?
If so please install Application request routing and enable forward proxy in IIS manager->server node-> application request routing cache->Server proxy Settings->Enable proxy.

https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/application-request-routing

[image]
[image]
[image]

If it doesn't fix the problem, please enable failed request tracing and post what you have seen.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-failed-request-tracing-to-trace-rewrite-rules